# Processing PLUpload uploads with node.js

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, upload, plupload

I'm attempting to create a server-side upload component in node.js, but I'm having trouble interpreting the information sent from PLUpload. From what I can tell, PLUpload (in HTML5 mode) sends files as binary information, which creates problems for the node.js packages I've been attempting to use so far (node-formidable and node-express), as they expect normal HTML uploads with multipart content types.

For what it's worth, this is the code I've been attempting to use...

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var sys = require('sys');

http.createServer( function( req, res ){

    console.log('request detected');

    if( req.url == '/upload/' ){

        console.log('request processing');

        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse( req, function( err, fields, files ){
            res.writeHead( 200, {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://tksync.com',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
                'content-type': 'text/plain'
            });
            res.write('received upload:\n');
            res.end(sys.inspect({
                fields: fields,
                files: files
            }));
        });
    }

}).listen( 8080 );
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no problem to use plupload(in HTML5 mode) with node.js with below code:

```
module.exports.savePhoto= (req, res) ->
  if req.url is "/upload" and req.method.toLowerCase() is "post"
    console.log 'savePhoto: req.url=', req.url, 'req.method=', req.method
    form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
    files = []
    fields = []
    form.uploadDir = config.PATH_upload
    form.on("field", (field, value) ->
      console.log field, value
      fields.push [ field, value ]
    ).on("file", (field, file) ->
      console.log field, file
      files.push [ field, file ]
    ).on "end", ->
      console.log "-> upload done: fields=", fields
      console.log "received fields:", util.inspect(fields)
      console.log "received files:",  util.inspect(files)
      size = files[0][1].size
      pathList = files[0][1].path.split("/")
      #console.log 'pathList=', pathList
      file = pathList[pathList.length - 1]
      console.log "file=" + file
      ......
```

Answer (score 1):

I created [`node-pluploader`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-pluploader) to handle this, as I found elife's answer didn't work for chunked uploads, as said chunks come in on different requests.

Express-based usage example:

```
var Pluploader = require('node-pluploader');

var pluploader = new Pluploader({
  uploadLimit: 16
});

 /*
  * Emitted when an entire file has been uploaded.
  *
  * @param file {Object} An object containing the uploaded file's name, type, buffered data & size
  * @param req {Request} The request that carried in the final chunk
  */
pluploader.on('fileUploaded', function(file, req) {
  console.log(file);
});

/*
  * Emitted when an error occurs
  *
  * @param error {Error} The error
  */
pluploader.on('error', function(error) {
    throw error;
});

// This example assumes you're using Express
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
  pluploader.handleRequest(req, res);
});
```